# Why does my recursive CTE with duplicate rows in underlaying table result in a infinite loop?

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I'm experimenting with a recursive CTE.

I have the following table `#temp`:

[image: tmptable]

And the following recursive CTE:

```
WITH CTE_ASS (OCRA_Code, Pre_Code, Pre_CodeEnd, NAV_Code) 
AS
(
SELECT OCRA_Code,Pre_Code, Pre_CodeEnd, CAST(Pre_Code AS int) AS NAV_Code
FROM #temp

UNION ALL

SELECT a.OCRA_Code, a.Pre_Code, a.Pre_CodeEnd, b.NAV_Code + 1 AS NAV_Code
FROM #temp a
INNER JOIN CTE_ASS b ON a.OCRA_Code = b.OCRA_Code 
                AND b.NAV_Code BETWEEN a.Pre_Code AND a.Pre_CodeEnd -1

)
SELECT OCRA_Code AS ocra_account, NAV_Code AS nav_account
FROM CTE_ASS
```

The resultset returns 145 rows as intended.

But if I insert duplicate rows (
`insert into #temp select * from #temp)` to the `#temp` table (there is no PK constraint) the CTE will fail with an infinite loop.

Why does it result in an infinite loop?

Comment: Maybe not infinite, but exponential in time? Maybe the temporary result sets are doubled at each recursion step.

Comment: It is because there is no end to the recursion when you have duplicates like that. It ends up being a circular reference.

Comment: it's not a circular reference..  you'd get a recursion limit error if that was the case..   for every gap you have in your Pre_Code and Pre_CodeEnd you are basically doubling the number of records you're creating..    so when the gap is 2, it creates 2 records for the first number, then 4 records the second and so on.. so you get 2, 4, 8, 16, 32..